# I want to change the structure of my array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to modify a data which is coming from API. The data is coming in the form of array of objects.

```
const crosses = [
{
  fatherLineId: 8,
  fatherLineName: "2ART18-0008",
  id: 54,
  motherLineId: 5,
  motherLineName: "2ART18-0005",
},
{
  fatherLineId: 3
  fatherLineName: "2ART18-0003",
  id: 55,
  motherLineId: 5,
  motherLineName: "2ART18-0005",
}
]
```

I want my data to be restructured in the form of:

```
const resultantArr = [
{
 enteryNumber: 1,
 ParentName: "2ART18-0008"
},
{
 entryNumber: 2,
 ParentName: "2ART18-0005",
},
{
 entryNumber: 3,
 ParentName: "2ART18-0003"
},
and so on ...

];
```

Here the parentName property will have motherLineName values and fatherLineName values in the order.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. And perhaps explain how this is related to React.

Comment: are father- and motherLineName allways the same? if not, how do you know which goes into the ParentName? Is entryNumber the entry number in the first array?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the result of the api call, loop through it and map the data toy our custom object, I can't provide a complete example based on your question but something like this:

You may also need to parse the apiresult into json using JSON.parse()

```
var resultantArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < apiresult.length; i++)
{
  resultantArr.push({"enteryNumber" : i + 1 , "ParentName" : apiresult[i].fatherLineName });
}
```

Comment: Your code won't work because it's missing the `motherLineName`.

Comment: Indeed it isn't a complete example but the question isn't clear on when to use father or mother line. The basic idea is there though and should provide some guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array and push two separate objects into an output array. And keep a record of each object entryname that you increment by two at the end of each iteration.

```js
const crosses=[{fatherLineId:8,fatherLineName:"2ART18-0008",id:54,motherLineId:5,motherLineName:"2ART18-0005"},{fatherLineId:3,fatherLineName:"2ART18-0003",id:55,motherLineId:5,motherLineName:"2ART18-0005"}];

const out = [];
let count = 1;

crosses.forEach(obj => {

  const { fatherLineName, motherLineName } = obj;

  out.push({
    entryNumber: count,
    parentName: fatherLineName
  });
  
  out.push({
    entryNumber: count + 1,
    parentName: motherLineName
  });

  count = count + 2;

});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you...

```
const crosses = [
  {
    fatherLineId: 8,
    fatherLineName: "2ART18-0008",
    id: 54,
    motherLineId: 5,
    motherLineName: "2ART18-0005",
  },
  {
    fatherLineId: 3,
    fatherLineName: "2ART18-0003",
    id: 55,
    motherLineId: 5,
    motherLineName: "2ART18-0005",
  }
];

var result = [];
var count = 1;

crosses.forEach(cross => {
  result.push({
    parentName: cross.fatherLineName,
    entryNumber: count++,
  }),

  result.push({ parentName: cross.motherLineName,
    entryNumber: count++,
  })
});

result
```